# jQuery Click by class not working

Tags: jquery, class, events, click

I have the following html code in bootstrap:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-heading"> 
                            <h3>Team Meta Data</h3>
                        </div><!--panel heading end-->
                        <hr>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="team-meta-form">
                            <input type="hidden" id="option" name="option" value="12">
                            <input type="hidden" id="tab-type" name="tab-type" value="team">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="team-meta-page-title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Meta Page Title:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-meta-page-title" name="meta-page-title">
                                </div>
                                <span class="col-xs-3">(Enter Page Title)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="team-meta-page-description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Meta Page Description:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-meta-page-description" name="meta-page-description">
                                </div>
                                <span class="col-xs-3"> (Enter Meta Page Description)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="team-meta-keywords" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Meta Keywords:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-meta-keywords" name="meta-keywords">
                                </div>
                                <span class="col-xs-3">(Enter Meta Keywords)</span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg" id="team-meta-submit" class="add_meta_submit">Save Changes</button>
                            <br><div id="teammetamsg" name="teammetamsg"></div>
                        </div><!--panel footer end-->
                    </div><!--panel end-->
```

The button has the class "add_meta_submit". There are about 6 similar bootstrap panes all inside one main div. Each pane also has its own form. I created a super simple click handler as follows.

```js
$('.add_meta_submit').click(function(){
        alert("click worked");
    });
```

This is totally not working. If I access the click event by id like this:

$("#meta-submit").click(function(){

it works every time. The class event I cannot get to work. I have 6 forms with very similar data and I would like to simply capture all the forms and send them to the same backend function. Basically I want to start the function from the class click then based on the id of the element click serialize the form and send it to the backend.

Comment: Try to put the class in double quotes `""`. Like this `$(".add_meta_submit")`

Comment: @d3r1ck ... no.

Comment: No what? It didn't still work? Try to view the browser JS console to see if it logs any errors.

Comment: One element cannot have two identical attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *class=""* two times, that's the error, here you go

```js
$(".add_meta_submit").click(function(){
        alert("click worked");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-   bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-heading"> 
                            <h3>Team Meta Data</h3>
                        </div><!--panel heading end-->
                        <hr>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="team-meta-form">
                            <input type="hidden" id="option" name="option" value="12">
                            <input type="hidden" id="tab-type" name="tab-type" value="team">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="team-meta-page-title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Meta Page Title:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-meta-page-title" name="meta-page-title">
                                </div>
                                <span class="col-xs-3">(Enter Page Title)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="team-meta-page-description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Meta Page Description:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-meta-page-description" name="meta-page-description">
                                </div>
                                <span class="col-xs-3"> (Enter Meta Page Description)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="team-meta-keywords" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Meta Keywords:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-meta-keywords" name="meta-keywords">
                                </div>
                                <span class="col-xs-3">(Enter Meta Keywords)</span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg add_meta_submit" id="team-meta-submit" >Save Changes</button>
                            <br><div id="teammetamsg" name="teammetamsg"></div>
                        </div><!--panel footer end-->
                    </div><!--panel end-->
```

Hope this works!

Comment: That was totally it Francisco Fernandez. I added so many things over a long period of time that I couldn't see the obvious anymore. I already defined a class for bootstrap. I didn't even see it anymore because I copied and pasted from a template so many times. So I added another class definition. This was definitely a second set of eyes required thing.

Comment: tried to up vote you but I dont have the credentials.

Answer (score -1):

First check if you have Jquery properly linked. Check script src. It's good then change class to id. If you want to use class then put an id on a parent div.

```
$('#parent_id .yourclass').click();
```

Comment: the id case working rules out jquery not being properly linked.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I will try all of these tonight.